# Programmatically generated layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm getting some data from an API and generating and Android layout, but I can't achieve a beautiful layout as you can see below.

[image]

I want TextView -> RadioGroup below TextView for every new data I receive. It's always a question and a radio group.

Here's my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int size = intent.getIntExtra("size", 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - Qtd Questões: " + size);

        ScrollView scrollView= new ScrollView(this);
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        for (int i=0; i<size;i++) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setId(i+1);
            tv1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("q"+i));
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());

            // Initialize a new RadioGroup
            RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
            rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
            params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tv1.getId());
            rg.setId(i+1);

            // Create a Radio Button for RadioGroup
            RadioButton rb_sim = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
            rb_sim.setText("Sim");
            rb_sim.setId(i+i);
            rg.addView(rb_sim);

            RadioButton rb_nao = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
            rb_nao.setText("Não");
            rb_nao.setId(i+i);
            rg.addView(rb_nao);

            RadioButton rb_na = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
            rb_na.setText("Não se Aplica");
            rb_na.setId(i+i);
            rg.addView(rb_na);

            if (i > 0) {
                params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rg.getId());
                layout.addView(tv1,params1);
            } else {
                layout.addView(tv1);
            }
            layout.addView(rg, params2);
        }

        scrollView.addView(layout);
        setContentView(scrollView);
    }
```

Probably I'm near to it, but I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: As you have some list to render I think it is better to use `ListView` with `ArrayAdapter`, [look here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView).

Comment: It is better to use RecyclerView, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the layout Relative to Linear and then check the output.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

To

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Hope this show your view as normal not overlapping the textView.

Comment: The radio went a bit more inside tv1 with it.